# Which traits are better for a control/(de)buff Witch at level 4?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, optimization, witch

Going to make a level 4 witch. I have narrowed my list of traits down to the following. Which 2 of these 4 options is better for a battlefield control/debuffer/buffer build?

- +2 Initiative (already +10)
- +2 Concentration (already +10)
- +4 Perception (already +7)
- add Prestidigitation to cantrip list

I guess generally I want to know what it more useful over the course of a campaign:

- Going first
- Ensuring a spell goes off
- Perception
- Prestidigitation

Comment: It may help to know what your party consists of as well. E.g. some party setups may require that you have your perception high, where others perception will be heavily covered and you could afford something else.

Comment: @BaseHobo This I don't know until the adventure begins. I think at a minimum, there is a ranger and a fighter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Take the trait granting the +2 bonus on [initiative checks](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Initiative) then the trait granting the +4 bonus on [Perception](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/perception) skill checks

Whether casting a battlefield control spell, a spell that buffs your allies, or a spell that debuffs your foes, casting that spell *first* is vitally important to you and your party's survival. But, while you want your [initiative result](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Initiative) to beat your foes', you *can't* go first if you fail a [Perception](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/perception) skill check, and your foes murder you during the [surprise round](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Surprise), so, obviously, the [Perception](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/perception) skill—the game's most important and, arguably, *best* skill—is vital, too. So take those two traits.

By way of comparison, if you've enough Perception that you *aren't* surprised, *and* you go first, you shouldn't *need* to make [concentration checks](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Concentration). No matter what, though, don't pick the [*prestidigitation*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/prestidigitation) option—an appropriate [*ioun stone* (cracked orange prism)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/ioun-stones/orange-prism-ioun-stone) adds *prestidigitation* to your spells known or spells prepared for 1,000 gp, and any [*cloak of the hedge wizard*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/c-d/cloak-of-the-hedge-wizard) grants *prestidigitation* usable at will for 2,500 gp (yet, oddly, a [*page of spell knowledge*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/m-p/page-of-spell-knowledge) can't help at all).